# Gnome-panel failed to acquire bus name (gnome-panel как добавление ярлыка для рабочего стола)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хочу организовать рабочий стол с помощью gnome-panel, используя https://losst.ru/dobavlenie-yarlyka-v-ubuntu

Установил gnome-panel

`$ sudo apt install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel`

Вызываю gnome-panel

`$ gnome-panel`

Получаю ошибку

`Failed to acquire bus name!`

Answer (score 0):

В статье не запускают gnome-panel, а только редактор ярлыков из комплекта.

Если хочется её запустить то установи gnome-session-flashback и выбери эту сессию при входе в систему.

Рабочий стол не запустится в 20ой убунте. Нужно использовать расширение gnome-shell или `nemo --desktop`